# Huge delay before call of GoogleAction.Finished

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm developing an action to allow people with different disabilities to access books read by volunteers.

Mp3 can be from 10 seconds to half an hour. After one file end i expect my action to get the GoogleAction.Finished request to play the next chapter.

The action works fine on my phone's assistant, but in my nest mini 2 i have to wait several minutes of complete silence to get che GoogleAction.Finished call.

Any ideas on how i could fix it or at least debug this?

Comment: It isn't clear how you're playing the mp3 and handling the Finished response. Seeing your code and a screen shot of how you're handling the event will help us help you a bit better.

Comment: In these two scenarios you described above, did the phone and nest mini play the same mp3 file?

Can you try to play the same mp3 file for the phone, nest mini and also in the actions simulator in the console to see if the huge delay happens in the simulator as well?

This will help me understand if this is a device specific issue.